# Can socket.io support callbacks when sending to a specific client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When using the socket.io server and sending to a specific client with `socket.to('destination').emit('event', 'message', callBackFunction);` it throws an error:

> Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting

I have multiple separate socket.io server nodes. So I use socket.io-redis to emit. I can't access socket project on different server node.

Now I am doing a private chat between clients. One client send massage to server, then server send message to another client. Here I use

```js
socket.to('destination').emit('event', message)
```

But I can't use callback when I send this message to another client. It really bothers me.

There is my client code, use Java:

```
socket.on("private_chat", new Emitter.Listener() {
  @Override
  public void call(Object... args) {
    Ack ack = (Ack) args[args.length - 1];
    ack.call();
  }
});
```

There is my server code:

```
// this is not support
socket.to(anotherClientId).emit('private_chat', data, function(){
  console.log('client receive message');
});
```

Is there any other function to make it work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: well socket.io client does support callbacks.

Comment: please share your client event code also the server handler